# 有向グラフの表現で、E = {⟨u, v⟩ | u|v,⟨u, v⟩ ∈ V × V and u ̸= v} の表すものが分からない

Tags: アルゴリズム, データ構造

有向グラフG=(V,E)の時、V = {1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 12} and E = {⟨u, v⟩ | u|v,⟨u, v⟩ ∈ V × V and u ̸= v} といった表現がされていた場合のEの右辺の表現が理解できません。この場合はどのようなグラフが期待されるのでしょうか？ご教示いただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

おそらく u|v の部分が分からないのだと思いますが、今回頂点は自然数なので u や v も自然数で、自然数に対する u|v という書き方だと約数を表す記号として使われているのだと思います。Wikipedia の[約数](http://%E7%B4%84%E6%95%B0)のページなどを参考にしてください。

ただしもちろん、プログラミングで関数を自由に定義できるように、数学でも定義さえすれば記号の意味は変わりうるので、何かしらの教科書などに書いてあったのだとすればその教科書での定義を確認してください。